# Explain the code of Z-order curve

Tags: python, z-order

In the explanation of `Z-order curve` in [`Wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), there is some `Python` code:

```
def less_msb(x, y):
    return x < y and x < (x ^ y)
```

Two questions here:

1. What is the `msb` short for ?
2. Since `x < y`, why should I compare `x` and `(x^y)` still ?

Answer (score 2):

`msb` is the [Most Significant Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit)

> One way to determine whether the most significant smaller is to compare the floor of the base-2 logarithm of each point. It turns out the following operation is equivalent, and only requires exclusive or operations:

```
def less_msb(x, y):
   return x < y and x < (x ^ y)
```

The second comparison is needed because, even if `x < y`, `x`'s `msb` isn't necessarily less than `y`'s `msb`:

For example `x = 2`, `y = 3`: `x < y` but `x` and `y` have the same `msb`:

```
print bin(2), bin(3)
0b10 0b11
```

You can see on the table below that `x^y` is not less than `x` until `y`'s bit_length is greater than `x`'s, until that point their `msb`s are equal:

```
(2, 3)   2^3 =  1   bin(2):   10    bin(3):    11
(2, 4)   2^4 =  6   bin(2):   10    bin(4):   100

(3, 4)   3^4 =  7   bin(3):   11    bin(4):   100

(4, 5)   4^5 =  1   bin(4):  100    bin(5):   101
(4, 6)   4^6 =  2   bin(4):  100    bin(6):   110
(4, 7)   4^7 =  3   bin(4):  100    bin(7):   111
(4, 8)   4^8 = 12   bin(4):  100    bin(8):  1000

(5, 6)   5^6 =  3   bin(5):  101    bin(6):   110
(5, 7)   5^7 =  2   bin(5):  101    bin(7):   111
(5, 8)   5^8 = 13   bin(5):  101    bin(8):  1000

(6, 7)   6^7 =  1   bin(6):  110    bin(7):   111
(6, 8)   6^8 = 14   bin(6):  110    bin(8):  1000

(7, 8)   7^8 = 15   bin(7):  111    bin(8):  1000

(8, 9)   8^9 =  1   bin(8): 1000    bin(9):  1001
(8,10)  8^10 =  2   bin(8): 1000   bin(10):  1010
(8,11)  8^11 =  3   bin(8): 1000   bin(11):  1011
(8,12)  8^12 =  4   bin(8): 1000   bin(12):  1100
(8,13)  8^13 =  5   bin(8): 1000   bin(13):  1101
(8,14)  8^14 =  6   bin(8): 1000   bin(14):  1110
(8,15)  8^15 =  7   bin(8): 1000   bin(15):  1111
(8,16)  8^16 = 24   bin(8): 1000   bin(16): 10000
```

Comment: Another question : When calculating `Z-values`, take two-dimensional as example, is it must `y`  before `x` when we `shuffle of x and y` ?